# How to get Division for api (exact online)

Tags: exact-online

i'm wondering how to get the `division` that is required for most api calls to the exact online platform.

Also the documentation suggests that I use `api/v1/current/Me` to be the first call however when running this I receive the following (which is useless):

```
array(3) { ["url"]=> string(46) "https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/current/Me" ["request"]=> array(0) { } ["response"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Hi @NealVDV, can you signal whether the answer provided is correct or whether there are any issues left?

Answer (score 5):

When you switch company in Exact Online, the URL of your browser will display the division of the newly selected company:

```
https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/MenuPortal.aspx?_Division_=123123
```

You can also query system/divisions or run on https://online-sql-editor.com (I work there) the following query:

```
select * from systemdivisions
```

Comment: It is not possible to do this via the API or oauth2 flow then?

Comment: Yes of course. All these statements are translated into api calls. Either rest on system divisions or xml on administrations. Note that system divisions also includes companies for independent subscriptions when queried from an accountancy subscription. For more depth please consult exact’s online documentation or contact your support partner.